# Не учитывать знаки пунктуации в функции

Tags: c++, функции

Сейчас програма считает все после пробела как слова. Мне нужно чтобы не учитывались знаки пунктуации (. , ! ? )

```
string str;
        int arr[64] = { 0 };
        while (!Txt.eof())
        {
            int i = 0;
            int word = 0;
            int count2 = 0;
            
            getline(Txt, str);
            
            while (str[i] != '\0') {

                if (word == 0 && str[i] != ' ')
                {
                        word = 1;
                        count2++;
                }

                else if (str[i] == ' ')
                    word = 0;
                i++;
            }
            arr[0] += count2;
        }
```

Comment: Ну добавьте так же, как пробел, все эти знаки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб : можно добавить к пробелам все нужные знаки, через `&&`. А вообще я бы использовал [`isalpha()`](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/isalpha) при проверке.

Вместо

```
if (word == 0 && str[i] != ' ') {
word = 1;
count2++;
}
```

напишите

```
if (word == 0 && isalpha((unsigned char) str[i])){
word = 1;
count2++;
}
```

И все должно у Вас работать.

Comment: Лучше `isalpha((unsigned char)str[i])`, а то будет UB на символах с отрицательными номерами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Да, так лучше. Добавлю, но я думаю, автору хватит и этого.